# Understanding the difference between convergence in distribution and convergence almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I know that the sum of $\sum_{i=0}^nZ_i$ where $Z\sim N(0,1)$ has a distribution of a Chi squared distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom which in my understand means that $Z^2$ converges in distribution to a Chi square (correct me if I'm wrong).

The examples on Wikipedia show almost sure convergence with respect to a constant and not a RV. And in this case I'm pretty sure that there almost sure convergence does not happen with respect to a constant (again correct me if I'm wrong) the reason being that $Z_i$ itself is a random variable and therefore the sequence of ${Z_i}$'s will not converge to a value.

Now the part that I'm not sure about is that will $Z^2$ converge to a RV $X$ if $X\sim \chi(n)$ almost surely? Although I have the definitions down, I don't intuitively understand the difference between convergence in distribution and almost sure convergence.